# HIBERNATE: cant extract data from MySQL using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Sorry for bothering you. I'm newbie with hibernate and I have this silly problem. I can't deal with it on my own. Every time i'm trying to select data from DB, i'm getting syntax error, so I decided for dummy table (but the problem is the same like before):

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;
```

hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">qayxsw</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">training</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">training</property>
        <mapping resource="Test.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Test.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping> <!-- package="com.test" -->
    <class name="s.Test" catalog="training" table="test">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="name"/>   
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Test.java:

```
package s;


import java.util.Date;

/*import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;*/

//@Entity
//@Table(name = "user")
public class Test{

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Test(){

    }

    public Test(Integer id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import s.Test;

public class Main {

    public Session session;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main test = new Main();

        test.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        test.session.beginTransaction();

        //Query query = test.session.createQuery("from user where nick = Turdus");
        Query query = test.session.createQuery("from Test");

        final List<Test> pass = new LinkedList<Test>();
        query.list();
        for(final Object o : query.list()) {
            pass.add((Test)o);
        }

        for(Test password : pass){

            System.out.println(password.getName());
        }

        test.session.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Test.hbm.xml
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training]
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:15 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Mar 16, 2015 7:14:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.test test0_' at line 1
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:25)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.test test0_' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    ... 15 more
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: why is `//@Entity
//@Table(name = "user")` commented out?  Table name is `test` though

Comment: I renamed table. User has nothing to do with test table. I forgot to remove comments

Comment: But, the Test class should still have these annotations shouldn't it?

Comment: @Scary  He  commented hibernate annotations because he is using xml way "Test.hbm.xml"

Comment: @Turdus Can you confirm table test exist in database ? Can you connect to your database and run "Select * from test" and let us know what you get

Comment: @Farm yes, table exists in database training and I can also use SQL query to access the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution :). 
I enabled

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

and I realized that hibernate uses SQL query:

```
select test0_.id as id1_0_, test0_.name as name2_0_ from training.training.test test0_
```

So I removed catalog="training" attribute and now it works :)